# Phpunit acceptance test not finding redirect url

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to write a functional acceptance test for my facebook login integration in laravel using socalite.

This works manually.

if i try the following code

```
public function test_facebook_login()
{
   $this->visit('/')->click('Login With Facebook');
}
```

Then i get this error(Ihave removed api key and secret)

1) AuthenticationTest::test_facebook_login
A request to [https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id=[CLIENTID]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcore-DOMAIN%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=CODE] failed. Received status code [404].

if I copy that url and go to it manually in the browser it works and I can log in to FB

Comment: Have you tried accessing the URL using `curl` from the machine that runs the tests? Maybe there's a networking problem (although error 404 seems to indicate otherwise), or an issue with accessing SSL URLs. What happens if you try to access just `https://www.facebook.com` using your test?

Comment: I can curl that url and https:// from the commandline of the machine running the test